# Phonegap/cordova not adding android into my project

Tags: android, cordova

running this command `cordova platforms add android` should add a folder named android into my cordova app, but I keep getting an error no matter what I do, I did edit the `path` variable, installed ant added that to the variable, added java to the path, added cordova to the path...

**The Error**

```
[Error: The command `android` failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK
installed, and the `android` command (inside the tools/ folder) added to your pa
th. Output: ]
```

Guess what though, it is installed, maybe I don't have the `android` command (inside the tools/ folder)?

You can see I am downloading multiple android versions, just to test that.... this is killing me. Hopefully someone has an idea..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `PATH` contains path to Android SDK tools folder

In you r case it is `C:\Users\visum_000\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-20131030\sdk\tools\`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I have edited the path multiple times, using ; to separate my java, SDK and ant.. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.2\bin;C:\Users\visum_000\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Users\visum_000\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\tools;C:\Users\visum_000\AppData\Roaming\npm`

Comment: close your command prompt where you run `cordova platforms add android` and open again

Comment: I finally got it, I did a system restore to reset my path variables, I cleared the default path vars and I think that caused issues, not sure if it was that specifically, but deleting everything then doing a system restore and installing it in proper order helped me. Also I want to note I had to download android package 17, cordova wasnt working with the latest version 19.